# Is there a way to make the bounding box of a group rotate with the group in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, skew

I'm trying to skew square grouped art onto a "cube" shape (a hexagon). I can get the two sides, but the top "diamond" is hard to do because, when I rotate the square image to match the front edge of the diamond, the bounding box resets to align with the x and y axes, preventing me from warping it correctly.

[image: Illustrator Screenshot: group is rotated, but bounding box refit to the they highest/widest points]

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: This is strange - for me in CS6 (windows, recent install so few custom settings), it just works how you want - UNLESS I have something else not in the group selected. In fact the only way I can make it act like you say is by selecting the group *and* something else. Are you sure everything in your selection is properly grouped, *and* all objects are part of that group? Also, maybe try putting it all in a square clipping mask? Also, maybe try without the graphs, or after breaking (ungrouping) the graphs. The graph tool is ancient and is not compatible with many basic Illustrator functions.

Comment: I ended up just rotating the other parts by a numeric value for the change (so that I could leave the group to be skewed with one "horizontal" edge), then rotating them back.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what the object is and WHEN the object was rotated - current working session or previous session where the file has been closed and reopened. In addition to what has been done since the object was rotated, assuming it's still the current working session.

The primary thing is that the bounding box resets upon certain actions such as saving, expanding, copy/pasting, duplicating, transforming, etc. The bounding box has never been designed to stay rotated with the object, although it will do just that in some instances.

The issue with groups is that *each object* within the group *technically* has its own bounding box. So which box is the correct one to display? AI can not possibly determine that in most cases, so it creates one bounding box square to the artboard.

It does seem like it would be an easy matter for AI to "find the edges" of the group, determine corners, thus determine angle and create a bounding box... but it just doesn't work that way. Chalk this up to along the same lines of AI never remembering the degree of rotation for objects (like InDesign does). There's little reason that could *not* be part of the application, it just is not.

In many cases using `Effects > Distort & Transform > Transform` may be better to use, although less intuitive. Primarily because the effect *will* remember degrees of rotation along with other settings.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrestling with this today and found a fix for one case at least.

It turned out I'd rotated one of the objects in my group exactly 90 degrees, so it still looked axis-aligned. But when I grouped it together with other objects, Illustrator saw multiple different bounding box orientations and so it ignored them all and stuck with the default axis-aligned box for the group as a whole, even after I'd rotated it.

To fix this, I did the following:

1. Undo any rotation of the group so the contents are in an axis-aligned orientation.
2. Ungroup the objects
3. Select each object, and choose `Object -> Transform -> Reset Bounding Box`
4. Regroup the objects

Now that they all agree about what bounding box orientation they want, Illustrator will respect that consensus as we rotate the full group.

Answer (score 0):

selecting objects and hitting object>transform>reset bounding box will cause the outer bounding box to rotate with the objects until one of the objects is rotated relative to the others.

Comment: Please can you explain better what you mean, for example with an screenshoot?